# Train problem question in kinematics

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

engine of a train moving with uniform acceleration passes an electric pole with velocity u and the last
compartment with velocity v. The middle point of the train passes past the same pole with a velocity of.

My thinking:
Q1 Will the values of v and u be constant since they can’t pass it with different velocities because they are one thing.
Q2 Shouldn’t the middle part also cover it with u velocity.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will the values of v and u be constant since they can’t pass it with different velocities because they are one thing.

You are right in saying that two ends of a same rigid body can't have different values of speed but you should note that your line is correct only if you are talking about the speed of engine and the last compartment **at a given point of time**.

In your question , the engine passes the pole with speed $u$ and note that since the train can't elongate or compress , the speed of the middle part as well as the last compartment at that instant is $u$ .

When the last compartment reaches the pole, in that time interval the train has accelerated (first line of your question). So, at that instant, the speed of the engine , the middle part and the last compartment is $v$.

So your first question is just a mere confusion.

For the center of the train to pass the pole , the train has to travel for some time and since it is an accelerated motion , the speed with which it passes the pole is different than $u$.

**Note:** The value of speed with which the center passes the pole can be calculated using the three equation of motion involving constant acceleration :

$$ v = u + at$$
$$s = ut + \frac{1}{2} a t^2$$
$$v^2 = u^2 + 2as$$

Hope it helps .

Comment: Can’t we say that it either accelerated or retarded @Ankit.

Comment: @user279337 was it helpful ?

Comment: Yes it was sir .

Comment: @user279337 yes we can say . It depends upon what is given in the question.

Comment: Ok thank you sir,

Answer (score 0):

> Q1 Will the values of v and u be constant since they can’t pass it with different velocities because they are one thing.

you misinterpreted the question. Actually the question is saying that engine passes by the pole and for the end compartment has to cover the length of train to reach the pole to byepass it but in the time it reaches there it had already acclerated from $u$ velocity to $v$ velocity

> Q2 Shouldn’t the middle part also cover it with u velocity.?

It is same as the above case as it had to cover a length i.e. half of the length of train to reach the pole and it will acquire a velocity that is between $u$ and $v$.

I hope that you might do the calculations yourself and I had clear your doubts.

Answer (score 0):

Someone on the train sees the pole go by.  As the pole travels the length of the train, x: $v^2$ = $u^2$ + 2ax.  This gives ax = ($v^2$ - $u^2$)/2.  For the pole to go half the length of the train the distance is, x/2.  Thus ${v_2}^2$ = $u^2$ + ($v^2$ - $u^2$)/2